# Laravel relational query takes a long time

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

In my database have service,transaction and vendor Adjustment table.Service table have 23 row and transaction table have more then two hundred thousand row and vendor Adjustment table have 30000 row.

My query is

```
$transactions = Service::withCount(['transactions as totalOrder','transactions as amount' =>
 function($query) use ($queryDate){
    $query->whereIn('status',['Success','Pending','Successful','Processing']);
    $query->whereDate('created_at','>=', $queryDate);
    $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(deducted)'));
},'vendorAdjustment as adjustmentPoint' => function($query) use ($queryDate){
    $query->whereDate('created_at','>=', $queryDate);
    $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount)"));
}])->get();
```

Now my above query take a long time .I cant understand how to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$transactions = Service::withCount(['transactions as totalOrder','transactions as amount' =>
        function($query) use ($queryDate){
            $query->whereIn('status',['Success','Pending','Successful','Processing']);
            $query->whereDate('created_at','>=', $queryDate);
        },'vendorAdjustment' => function($query) use ($queryDate){
        $query->whereDate('created_at','>=', $queryDate);
    }])->get();
```

Comment: How is that supposed to yield the desired result?

Comment: How can I get sum of deducted column  of transaction table?

Comment: @LaraDevelopment here you want to count relationship data right?

Comment: @LaraDevelopment in your query try to replace withCount to with and for count you have to add another method.

Answer (score 0):

I can see nothing wrong with your query. The problem might be that you are lacking specific indexes on your database. I asumme so because `whereDate('created_at', $queryDate)` will translate to `WHERE DATE(created_at) >= '$queryDate'` which has to extract the actual date from all timestamp/datetime records in the table before it can perform the comparison. Adding an index on the `created_at` column will make the task much easier for the database, although it has a slight impact on inserts, updates and deletes.

Therefore my best guess: add indexes for `transactions.created_at`, `transactions.status` and `vendor_adjustments.created_at`.